# Position absolute children on flatlist element in React Native (expo)

Tags: react-native, position, absolute

I want to make a little game when some circles comes from the top of the screen. After they appear they will drag down until they go out of the screen.

To make that i have a flatlist which contains all of the circles

```
 <FlatList scrollEnabled={false}renderItem={this.renderItem}data={this.state.elements} />
```

Then in the render item I insert the circle item view

```
   renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <Circle
        apparitionTime={new Date().getTime() / 1000}
        id={item.id}
        removeCircle={this.removeCircle}
        updateScore={this.updateScore}/>
);
```

A circle item looks like this :

```
  <Animated.View style={[/*this.moveAnimation.getLayout(),*/ styles.animatedView]}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.circleStyle} onPress={() => this.prepareToSend()}>
                <View style={styles.absoluteView}>
                </View>
                <Image style={styles.image} source={require('../assets/images/music.png')}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </Animated.View>
```

I use the animated view to make them scrolling all over the view.

I want the animated view to be on position absolute,but no matter what i've tried after sending the animated view to position absolute, the element disappear

```
   animatedView: {
    top: 0,
    zIndex: 100,
    width: 75,
    height: 75,
    position: "absolute", // does not work
},
```

Any Ideas ? Thank you

Comment: See this example, It is not using `FlatList` https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable/tree/master/Examples/MakeItRain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Position absolute didn't work inside a flatlist.**

Now how to render positional elements inside it !!!!!!!....

> Alternatively, you can use `alignSelf: 'flex-end'` or `alignSelf:
>   'flex-start'` and further you can place it by using margin/padding
>   inside the view. More you can read here about absolute not working in
>   their [official docs](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8923#issuecomment-391358698)

Comment: hey Nicolas Tran, you can upvote the answer as well if it works for you....Thanks :)